# java inheritance dealing with fields

Tags: java, inheritance, subclass, super

Say i have this code

```
public class A {
    String name = "a";
    public void one(){
        System.out.println(name);
    }
    public void two(){
        System.out.println(name);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        A a = new A();
        B b = new B();
        b.one();
    }
}

class B extends A{
    String name="b";
    public void two(){
        System.out.println(name);
    }
}
```

I cant figure out why b.one() always produces "a". From what i know of inheritance, B will see that it doesnt have its own copy of one() so it will super.one(). super.one() will print out the value of the variable name(a) in that class. However wont B see that it too has a name variable which has value "b" so wont it go to that? Im confused cause i know this logic works for method calls. Can anyone clarify this?

Comment: Short answer: You're hiding `name` by declaring another one in `B`. Fields don't override.

Comment: So, you've discovered that one field declaration doesn't override another, in the same way that method declarations do.  The JLS says this will happen.  I'm not sure what you want anyone to tell you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your own question partially answers itself. The moment you do `super.one()` you are no longer in 'B'. Thus, why would you expect anything else but "a" from the `name`. The `name` that you are referencing after you call the super class is the name of `A`. You could change the value of `name` in the subclass if `name` was `public` or `protected` and you did not re-declare it.

```
public class A
{
   protected String name;

   public void printName()
   {
      System.out.println(name);
   }
}

public class B extends A
{
    public B()
    {
        name = "b";
    }
}

public class Main 
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
       B b = new B();
       b.printName();
    }
}
```

The above code will print "B".